# Number of overlapping columns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with $m<n$. It is well-known that number of ways of choosing $k$ columns out of $n$ from $A$ is $\binom{n}{k}$, where ($k<m<n$). What is the number of ways of choosing $k$ columns from $A$ with only one overlapping column? Similarly,  two overlapping columns, and so on to $k-1$ overlapping columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean an overlapping column? Overlapping is always a relative term.

Comment: By overlapping columns I mean two sets of indices of $k$ columns where there is only one index that is common between the two sets. For example, consider a $3 \times 6 $ matrix and $k=2$. Consider two set of columns with indices $\{2,5\}$ and $\{2,6\}$. The overlapping column here is 2.

Comment: I am still not sure I understood your point. Are you asking how many pairs of two $k$-column sets can be chosen such that the two sets in each pair have exactly one common column? For instance, for a $2\times 4$ with $k = 2$, we have $(\{1,2\},\{1,3\})$, $(\{1,2\},\{1,4\})$, $(\{1,3\},\{1,4\})$, $(\{2,1\},\{2,3\})$, $(\{2,1\},\{2,4\})$, $(\{2,3\},\{2,4\})$, $(\{3,1\},\{3,2\})$, $(\{3,1\},\{3,4\})$, $(\{3,2\},\{3,4\})$, $(\{4,1\},\{4,2\})$, $(\{4,1\},\{4,3\})$, and $(\{4,2\},\{4,3\})$. That is 12.

Comment: In the example you have given what I need are $\{1,2\},\{1,3\}$ and $\{1,4\}$. That is 3. The overlapping column in these sets is 1. The order is not important.

Comment: Okay, got it. You are looking for the ${ maximum}$ number of ways of choosing $k$ columns such that all the choosings have one common column.

Comment: Exactly. In need to find how many number of ways possible to choose $k$ columns such that all the choosing have only one, two and so on to $k-1$ columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is $\lfloor \frac{n-m}{k-m}\rfloor$, where $m$ is the number of common columns, $k$ is the number of columns chosen and $n$ is the total number of columns.

Here is the argument: But for the $m$ common columns, the remaining $k-m$ columns of any two pairs have to be mutually disjoint. And to maximize such set of choosings, the $n-m$ columns have to be split into as many parts as possible, with each part size $k-m$. This split will have size $\lfloor \frac{n-m}{k-m}\rfloor$.

Comment: Thank you. But  I am not sure about the answer. The total number of sets should be $\binom{n}{k}$ isn't it? $n$ is the number of columns and $k$ is the size of the subset of columns from $n$

Comment: The answer I gave originally was for $m = k-1$. I have updated my answer for the general case.

Comment: Hello Shash! Thank you for your reply. I have got partial answer from your reply. Can you give me  your email so that we discuss about the problem over email.